# how to listen to localhost port in flutter windows

Tags: flutter, localhost, flutter-windows

I want to listen to a specific localhost port using Windows Filter.
This is to be able to create an **interface between the browser and Windows** so that I can execute a series of commands in Windows

Comment: Just use a vanilla Dart server socket: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-io/ServerSocket/bind.html

Comment: Or if you really want an HTTP server check out shelf